# Sitecore: Field type that has both the options from multiline-text and RichText?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Is it possible to have a field in Sitecore (6.5) that is a "merge" of multiline-text and RichText? 
More specificly, what i am looking for, is a RichText field, where i can insert content into the field, without opening the editor first. Just like you can with a multiline-text field.

So a RichText editor field, with the standard options, but also the ability to paste/enter text into the plain field without opening the editor it self?

Answer (score 2):

Select the "View" tab in Sitecore and check the "Raw Values" box. Now your Rich-Text fields will display the HTML contents. In Raw Values mode, you can edit, copy and paste raw HTML without opening any editors. This will also cause other fields to have their raw values exposed. You can stay in raw values mode and edit other items or exit out of it at any time.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily paste in plain text into a Rich Text field. In the content editor, just click on the "Show HTML" link above the RT field. That will open up the plain text editor, instead of the RTE.